# Whenever I try to take the load time from the android web view it gives me the wrong number

Tags: android, url, android-webview, performance-testing, timing

Whenever I try to take the load time from the android web view it keeps giving me the same number of `1.5701998E12` seconds for any website I load up I know my internet is slow but I don't think its that slow.I've been trying to solve the problem but I have no luck.

```
package com.example.new_app;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    float end;
    final Context context = this;
    String UR_L;
    String numberAsString;
    float start;
    float total;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {

                start = (new Date()).getTime();

            }

            //This function will take in the finished load time and create an alert

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                end = (new Date()).getTime();
                total=end-start;
                numberAsString = String.valueOf(total);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set title
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Load Time");

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setMessage(numberAsString)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.Google.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get the time. It returns a `long`. So, you need to change `start` and `end` to `long`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    long end;
    long start;
    float total;
    ...
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url) {
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                total = end - start;
                // Total is the difference in milliseconds.
                // Dividing by 1000, you convert it to seconds
                numberAsString = String.valueOf(total / 1000);
                ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and my return number is now in billions

Comment: That time is in milliseconds. Dividing by 1000, you have the time in seconds. I updated the answer

Comment: The number is still huge

Comment: I changed total to float. For me, that code is working. I'm getting: Total: 3.586 start: 1570465864873 end: 1570465868459

Comment: Because my start is 0 for some reason

Comment: Did you also changed: "start = System.currentTimeMillis();"? I just created a test app and added the code I show you. It is working fine for me.

Comment: yes please do because i literally have it set up exactly the way u do